# Google Areachart show only some months on x-axis, not all date intervals

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using a google AreaChart, but it doesn't display the x axis as I like it to be.

This is the data I like to plot

```
[new Date(2017, 02,10),1,'1'],
[new Date(2017, 02,21),1,'1'],
[new Date(2017, 02,28),1,'1'],
[new Date(2017, 03,07),1,'1'],
[new Date(2017, 03,14),1,'1'],
[new Date(2017, 03,23),1,'1'],
[new Date(2017, 03,31),1,'1'],
[new Date(2017, 04,07),1,'1'],
[new Date(2017, 04,26),1,'1'],
[new Date(2017, 05,03),1,'1'],
[new Date(2017, 05,10),1,'1'],
[new Date(2017, 05,17),1,'1'],
[new Date(2017, 05,25),1,'1'],
[new Date(2017, 06,05),1,'1'],
[new Date(2017, 06,12),0.5,'0.5']
```

I like the date intervals on the X-axis

The options for this chart are

```
   var options = {
            legend: {position: 'top', alignment: 'start', textStyle: {fontSize: 12, bold: false}},
            width: 800,
            height: 500,
            hAxis: {showTextEvery: 0, slantedText: 'true', slantedTextAngle: 45},
            vAxis: {minValue: 0},
            colors: ['#C3D5BC'],
            trendlines: {0: {
                    labelInLegend: 'Trendline (Test)',
                    type: 'linear',
                    showR2: false,
                    visibleInLegend: true,
                    color: '#344F35'
                }}    // Draw a trendline for data series 0.
        };
var container = document.getElementById("test-div");
var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(container);
chart.draw(data, options);
```

And this is my current output, but I like all date intervals on the x-axis???

[image: x-axis is not good]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can provide custom axis labels using option --> `ticks`

`ticks` should be an array of values with the same type as the axis,
in this case `'date'`

```
ticks: [new Date(2017, 02,10), new Date(2017, 02,11), ...]
```

see following working snippet...
here, data table method --> `getDistinctValues`
is used to build an array of unique dates from the data
this will only show the dates for which there is data

```
hAxis: {
  format: 'M/d/yy',
  ticks: data.getDistinctValues(0),
  ...
```

(also added `format` option to change format of the label)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Value', {role: 'tooltip'}],
    [new Date(2017, 02,10),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 02,21),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 02,28),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 03,07),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 03,14),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 03,23),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 03,31),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 04,07),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 04,26),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 05,03),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 05,10),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 05,17),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 05,25),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 06,05),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 06,12),0.5,'0.5']
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: {position: 'top', alignment: 'start', textStyle: {fontSize: 12, bold: false}},
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    hAxis: {
      format: 'M/d/yy',
      ticks: data.getDistinctValues(0),
      slantedText: 'true',
      slantedTextAngle: 45
    },
    vAxis: {minValue: 0},
    colors: ['#C3D5BC'],
    trendlines: {0: {
      labelInLegend: 'Trendline (Test)',
      type: 'linear',
      showR2: false,
      visibleInLegend: true,
      color: '#344F35'
    }}
  };
  var container = document.getElementById('test-div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="test-div"></div>
```

---

if you want to show all dates, whether there is data or not,
use data table method --> `getColumnRange`
`getColumnRange` will return the min and max dates from the data
use this to build an array of all the dates

```
var dateRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
var oneDay = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
var ticks = [];
for (var i = dateRange.min.getTime(); i < dateRange.max.getTime(); i = i + oneDay) {
  ticks.push(new Date(i));
}
```

note: there must be enough room on the chart,
or all the labels will not be displayed...

---

**UPDATE**

object notation can be used in place of literal values,
in the data table, and other places such as chart option `ticks`...

object notation accepts keys for...
`v:` - value
`f:` - formatted value
`p:` - custom properties (not displayed on the chart)

```
{v: new Date(2017, 1, 10), f: 'Feb 28, 17', p: {custom: 'value'}}
```

when used in the data table,
the default tooltip will show the formatted value

when used in `ticks`,
the axis label will display the formatted value

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Value'],

    // use object notation here to change the default tooltip
    [{v: new Date(2017, 1, 10), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},1],
    [{v: new Date(2017, 1, 21), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},1],
    [{v: new Date(2017, 1, 28), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},1],
    [{v: new Date(2017, 2, 7), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},1],
    [{v: new Date(2017, 2, 14), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},1],
    [{v: new Date(2017, 2, 23), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},1],
    [{v: new Date(2017, 2, 31), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},1],
    [{v: new Date(2017, 3, 7), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},1],
    [{v: new Date(2017, 3, 26), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},1],
    [{v: new Date(2017, 4, 3), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},1],
    [{v: new Date(2017, 4, 10), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},1],
    [{v: new Date(2017, 4, 17), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},1],
    [{v: new Date(2017, 4, 25), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},1],
    [{v: new Date(2017, 5, 5), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},1],
    [{v: new Date(2017, 5, 12), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},0.5]
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: {position: 'top', alignment: 'start', textStyle: {fontSize: 12, bold: false}},
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    hAxis: {
      format: 'M/d/yy',
      ticks: [
        // use object notation here to change the axis label
        {v: new Date(2017, 1, 10), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},
        {v: new Date(2017, 1, 21), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},
        {v: new Date(2017, 1, 28), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},
        {v: new Date(2017, 2, 7), f: 'Feb 28, 17'},
        {v: new Date(2017, 2, 14), f: 'Feb 28, 17'}
      ],
      slantedText: 'true',
      slantedTextAngle: 45
    },
    vAxis: {minValue: 0},
    colors: ['#C3D5BC'],
    trendlines: {0: {
      labelInLegend: 'Trendline (Test)',
      type: 'linear',
      showR2: false,
      visibleInLegend: true,
      color: '#344F35'
    }}
  };
  var container = document.getElementById('test-div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="test-div"></div>
```

---

data table method --> `getDistinctValues(colIndex)`
returns a simple array, with the values from the column

the first column in this example would return an array of the date values...

```
[new Date(2017, 1, 10), new Date(2017, 1, 21), ...]
```

in order to convert this array to object notation,
you could use the `map` method, or a number of other routines...

the following snippet creates object notation using the date values from the data,
all with the same formatted value

```
var ticks = data.getDistinctValues(0);
ticks = ticks.map(function (xDate) {
  return {
    v: xDate,
    f: 'Feb 28, 2017'
  };
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Value', {role: 'tooltip'}],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 10),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 21),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 28),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 7),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 14),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 23),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 31),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 7),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 26),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 3),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 10),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 17),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 25),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 5),1,'1'],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 12),0.5,'0.5']
  ]);

  var ticks = data.getDistinctValues(0);
  ticks = ticks.map(function (xDate) {
    return {
      v: xDate,
      f: 'Feb 28, 2017'
    };
  });

  var options = {
    legend: {position: 'top', alignment: 'start', textStyle: {fontSize: 12, bold: false}},
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    hAxis: {
      format: 'M/d/yy',
      ticks: ticks,
      slantedText: 'true',
      slantedTextAngle: 45
    },
    vAxis: {minValue: 0},
    colors: ['#C3D5BC'],
    trendlines: {0: {
      labelInLegend: 'Trendline (Test)',
      type: 'linear',
      showR2: false,
      visibleInLegend: true,
      color: '#344F35'
    }}
  };
  var container = document.getElementById('test-div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="test-div"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, note: `showTextEvery` only works for a _discrete_ axis (string values), not for a _continuous_ axis (date, number, etc.)...

Comment: One major problem I see the dates aren't correct, the dates in the chart are off by 1 month, why is this? See begin date starts at 10th of march (not feb) and end date 12 july and not 12 june as the dates in the rows shows???

need to readup on showTextEvery. So the only change is to use ticks? Are there any other nice things to do with ticks?

Comment: the month number in javascript is zero-based (0=Jan, 1=Feb, 2=March), when using the following constructor --> `new Date(year, month, day, ...)` -- as such, `new Date(2017, 02,28)` = March 28, 2017 -- `ticks` is just an array of values that should appear on the axis -- you can use object notation to provide both the axis value (`v:`) and formatted value (`f:`) --> `[{v: new Date(2017, 1, 28), f: 'Feb 28, 2017'}]`

Comment: hi, I am trying your object notation suggestion with some hardcoded `data.addRows([
[{v:new Date(2017, 02-1,10),f:'Feb 28, 2017'},1,'1'],
[{v:new Date(2017, 02-1,21),f:'Feb 28, 2017'},1,'1'],
[{v:new Date(2017, 02-1,28),f:'Feb 28, 2017'},1,'1'],` and I expect haxis to show all Feb 218, 2017 but it doesn't? it show the v:

Comment: oh wait it should be "in" ticks? but how do I combine it with `data.getDistinctValues(0),` in the google documentation I see: `hAxis: { ticks: [{v:32, f:'thirty two'}, {v:64, f:'sixty four'}] }` but in ticks I should plot every point???

Comment: wow splendid explanation. Need to reread this a couple of times and make a decision how many dates to show on the haxis.
You really know your Google Charts or are they called -WhiteHat Charts-  ;)